# How to convert 2 Bytes ASCII (ISO/IEC 8859-1) character to UTF8 character?

Tags: c, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, latin1

I want to convert **2 Bytes ASCII (ISO/IEC 8859-1) Latin-1 character to UTF8 character** in `C` language.
Value of Latin-1 character is, from **`C3 80`** to **`C3 BF`** as described on [this website](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/).

Below is information.
I have one ready made code and I want to display a Keyboard with Latin-1 character set.
Some logic has been implemented already for decoding purpose but it work in some specific condition only.

```
char key_latin[20];    // one ROW of keyboard
unsigned int codepoint;

key_latin[0]=0xC3;                  
key_latin[1]=0x00;
key_latin[2]=0xC3;                  
key_latin[3]=0x00;

codepoint = ((key_latin[0] & 0x1C) << 6) + (key_latin[0] & 0x03) <<6) + key_latin[1] & 0x3F);    //implemented logic
```

Then it displaying correctly 'À' and the value of `codepoint` = 0xC0 but it displaying only one character and other characters are not displaying in same ROW.

When I do like below,(as reference from above link)

```
char key_latin[20];    // one ROW of keyboard
unsigned int codepoint;

key_latin[0]=0xC3;                  
key_latin[1]=0xA0;
key_latin[2]=0xC3;                  
key_latin[3]=0xA1;

codepoint = ((key_latin[0] & 0x1C) << 6) + (key_latin[0] & 0x03) <<6) + key_latin[1] & 0x3F);    //implemented logic
```

Its shows nothing on screen.

My main point of asking is that,

> How can I display or encode *the 2 Bytes ASCII (ISO/IEC 8859-1)
>   Latin-1* to *UTF8* into `C`?
>
> Is it necessary to take value of other 1-Byte `(0xA0)` in encoding?

Please, let me know your suggestions and possible ways regarding to display the ASCII (ISO/IEC 8859-1) Latin-1 character.

*[If need more information related to this issue then please let me know.]*

Comment: Why are you overwriting `key_latin[0]` and `key_latin[1]` with the same values?

Comment: Use [iconv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/iconv.3.html) & read [utf8everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/)....

Comment: 0xc3 0x80 is already UTF-8.

Comment: 8859-1 is an 8bit / 1 byte encoding mechanism. Two bytes in 8859-1 is two characters. :/

Comment: `À` _Latin Capital Letter A With Grave_ is Unicode code point `U+00C0` and UTF-8 byte sequence `0xC3`,`0x80`. ISO/IEC 8859-1 was incorporated as the first 256 code points of Unicode. What conversion are you interested in?